# How to close previous accordion when i click on next item in accordion?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i had created accordion but i want to close previous accordion when i click on nect accordion.
But when i click on next accordion previoes accordion is not closing
How can i solve this one?
please help me

```
> <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta name="viewport"
> content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <style> .accordion {  
> background-color: #eee;   color: #444;   cursor: pointer;   padding:
> 18px;   width: 100%;   border: none;   text-align: left;   outline:
> none;   font-size: 15px;   transition: 0.4s; }
> 
> .active, .accordion:hover {   background-color: #ccc; }
> 
> .accordion:after {   content: '\002B';   color: #777;   font-weight:
> bold;   float: right;   margin-left: 5px; }
> 
> .active:after {   content: "\2212"; }
> 
> .panel {   padding: 0 18px;   background-color: white;   max-height:
> 0;   overflow: hidden;   transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out; }
> </style> </head> <body>
> 
> <h2>Accordion with symbols</h2> <p>In this example we have added a
> "plus" sign to each button. When the user clicks on the button, the
> "plus" sign is replaced with a "minus" sign.</p> <button
> class="accordion">Section 1</button> <div class="panel">   <p>Lorem
> ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
> veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
> ea commodo consequat.</p> </div>
> 
> <button class="accordion">Section 2</button> <div class="panel">  
> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
> eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
> minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
> aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p> </div>
> 
> <button class="accordion">Section 3</button> <div class="panel">  
> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
> eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
> minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
> aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p> </div>
> 
> <script> var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion"); var
> i;
> 
> for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {   acc[i].addEventListener("click",
> function() {
>     this.classList.toggle("active");
>     var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
>     if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
>       panel.style.maxHeight = null;
>     } else {
>       panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
>     }    }); } </script>
> 
> </body> </html>
```

Thanks
Somasekhar

Comment: first of all, when you click on accordion. active class is toggled on that child, when you click on other child then active class is toggled on that child.  What you need to do is search for the active class in every child on click, and remove the active class from every child, and add active class on that clicked child

Comment: could you please show me where i have to change

Comment: refer this for pure css solution https://codepen.io/Tuna_/pen/KKzXEVO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if there's an existing `active` class element, and remove it as well. Otherwise you are just toggling the one you clicked.

```js
let acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion"); 
 
for (let i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {   
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if(this.classList.contains('active')){
      this.classList.remove("active");
       panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      if(document.querySelector('.accordion.active')){
        document.querySelector('.accordion.active').nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
        document.querySelector('.accordion.active').classList.remove('active');
      }
      this.classList.add("active");
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  

  }); 
}
```

```css
.accordion{background-color: #eee;   color: #444;   cursor: pointer;   padding:
 18px;   width: 100%;   border: none;   text-align: left;   outline:
 none;   font-size: 15px;   transition: 0.4s; }
 
 .active, .accordion:hover {   background-color: #ccc; }
 
 .accordion:after {   content: '\002B';   color: #777;   font-weight:
 bold;   float: right;   margin-left: 5px; }
 
 .active:after {   content: "\2212"; }
 
 .panel {   padding: 0 18px;   background-color: white;   max-height:
 0;   overflow: hidden;   transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out; }
```

```html
<h2>Accordion with symbols</h2> <p>In this example we have added a
"plus" sign to each button. When the user clicks on the button, the
"plus" sign is replaced with a "minus" sign.</p> <button
class="accordion">Section 1</button> <div class="panel">   <p>Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
ea commodo consequat.</p> </div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button> <div class="panel">  
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p> </div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button> <div class="panel">  
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p> </div>
```